# how to change the numbers language in android studio?

Tags: android

whenever I change the size of the image manually. the height and width turn to Arabic numbers. I want the default language of the numbers to be English
here's the code after I change the image size.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="٢١١dp"
        android:layout_height="٢٢٤dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="166dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="521dp"
```

Comment: sorry, could you please tell more about what is current condition, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @JabalLogian my default numbers language is Arabic. the text is ok, in English. what happens is when I change the image size manually in the design(android studio) the numbers turn automatically to Arabic format. if i correct them then i resize the image using the curser it goes back to arabic

Comment: @AhmedLotfy, This is a problem with your keyboard settings, not your code.

Comment: @AhmedLotfy, it would also be great if you could upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a problem with your keyboard settings. You could either change the settings of your computer, or you could copy and paste some numerical values from [here](https://copypastelist.com/math/list-of-numbers-1-100/). This can get tedious, though with a large amount of numerical use. So if you don't type in Arabic often, then I recommend making your default to English keyboard. Good luck.